# Why on production server float numbers are returned with comma instead of decimal point?

Tags: php, symfony, server

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and i have an annoying problem.
With the exact same code on the local server and production server, whenever float numbers are returned from the production server they have comma instead of **decimal point** as it is on the **local server**.

For example instead of:

> 45.23

On the production server it returns:

> 45,23

It's weird because in the database of the production server the numbers have decimal points and i want to emphasize the fact that the code is identical on both servers so it must be a configuration problem of the production server but i have no idea what it might be.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Different locale? http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php Since this looks like you're relying on the default locale for formatting, you might want to specify that explicitly.

Comment: This would be correct link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php